# Run cmd in php with > operator

Tags: php, shell, cmd

I want to run a simple shell command, say:

```
dir > bau.txt
```

Using php:

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd ('dir > bau.txt');
shell_exec($cmd);
```

But it does not work (bau.txt stays empty).
Is there any reason for that?

A normal $cmd would work (say just 'dir').

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a similar scenario:

[How to run multiple commands in system, exec or shell_exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130677/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-system-exec-or-shell-exec)

Essentially when you use the > operator, you're piping your standard output to the file you've specified. It seems that shell_exec doesn't directly support piping, but rather, the output needs to be stored from shell_exec and then run through shell_exec with the next command.