# How to execute a cd followed by a java command in exec?

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to execute the given command in php

```
exec("cd C:\xampp\htdocs\Dynamic-Form-Processing-with-PHP\JavaApplication1\src && java -classpath C:\org.json.jar;C:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar;. javaapplication1.JavaApplication1")
```

It's just executing the first command i.e

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\Dynamic-Form-Processing-with-PHP\JavaApplication1\src
```

Please can you give me a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you might be interested in "proc-open" which has working directory as separate parameter.

Comment: i tried using proc-open but it does not execute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130677/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-system-exec-or-shell-exec

Comment: Does it work if you change the working directory with [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) instead of `cd`, then [change it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925679/how-to-use-chdir-to-change-to-current-directory) afterwards?